# Closing an advertisement with dynamic ID

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

First of all, I'd like to apologize for the lack of a serviceable example of what my code looks like. Unfortunately it contains personal information to access a database that has been made available to my university, so I cannot post it. The link to the databse is here: 
http://www.studiolegale.leggiditalia.it/#mode=home,__m=site.

Now, if you don't have a proper adblocker, you'll see that a spam popup window appears. I am building a scraper in python using Selenium, and the problem seems to be that I cannot find a way to close that window. I need to get rid of it for the purpose of my project, but I have no idea how. I tried creating an action chain to locate and click the 'X' button, but both the XPath and the ID of said button are dynamic.

I then noticed that the ID of the X button always contains 'close', so  I tried writing something like

```
spamlist = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id, "close")] ')
spamlist.click
```

but to no avail. It gives me no error but it doesn't close the window. I admit I am a bit of a beginner, but I really can't think of what I could be doing wrong. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

**EDIT 1.1**
I have been asked for the HTML code of 'close element' button. Here it is:

```
<div id="id70a13b6c7dclose70a13b6c7d" style="display: block !important; position: absolute !important; z-index: 10 !important; height: 70px !important; padding: 20px !important; margin-top: -20px !important; margin-left: -20px !important; box-sizing: border-box !important; left: 12px; right: auto; top: 12px; bottom: auto; transform: none; transform-origin: left top;"><div id="id70a13b6c7dclose-cross70a13b6c7d" style="display:block !important;height:30px !important;min-width:30px !important;background:#000 !important;border-radius:5px !important;border:2px solid #fff !important;white-space:nowrap !important;position:relative !important;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box !important;box-sizing:border-box !important;"><div id="id70a13b6c7dcross-container70a13b6c7d" style="overflow:visible !important;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box !important;box-sizing:border-box !important;"><div id="id70a13b6c7dcross70a13b6c7d" style="position:absolute !important;height:20px !important;width:20px !important;top:3px !important;left:3px !important;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAAOAgMAAABiJsVCAAAADFBMVEUAAAD///////////84wDuoAAAAA3RSTlMAgGJiSVzhAAAAOElEQVQI12PQYGBqYNjLwP6AYb+D/AMG+Qv1DgzsX/8yMDD+/8LAwFB/AUxAuGAJsBKwYrA2sAEADzMWbZHdzhcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) !important;background:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTQiIGhlaWdodD0iMTQiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNCAxNCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNLjcgMi43Yy0uNC0uNC0uNC0xIDAtMS40bC42LS42Yy40LS40IDEtLjQgMS40IDBMNyA1IDExLjMuN2MuNC0uNCAxLS40IDEuNCAwbC42LjZjLjQuNC40IDEgMCAxLjRMOSA3bDQuMyA0LjNjLjQuNC40IDEgMCAxLjRsLS42LjZjLS40LjQtMSAuNC0xLjQgMEw3IDlsLTQuMyA0LjNjLS40LjQtMSAuNC0xLjQgMGwtLjYtLjZjLS40LS40LS40LTEgMC0xLjRMNSA3IC43IDIuN3oiIGZpbGw9IiNGRkYiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0iZXZlbm9kZCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent) !important;background-size:20px !important;overflow:visible !important;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box !important;box-sizing:border-box !important;"></div></div><div id="id70a13b6c7dcounter70a13b6c7d" style="display:none !important;text-align:center !important;position:absolute !important;min-height:30px !important;min-width:30px !important;color:#fff !important;font:small-caps bold 18px/30px courier new, sans-serif !important;overflow:visible !important;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box !important;box-sizing:border-box !important;"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: I've opened it both in the normal window and in Incognito mode, but I'm not getting any pop-ups... Is it the 'cookie policy' bar on top?

Comment: @Alichino: indeed it doesn't show it when you open it with a browser, but it does give me this issue when I open it using chromedrive, for instance.

Comment: Hmm I still don't get the pop-up, even when using the chromedriver... Can you share the bit of code where you initialise the chromedriver and navigate to that page?

Comment: @Alichino I could give you the code of the first part, problem is I cannot give you the code where I navigate to the page, because before I get there I execute a log-in procedure that allows me to tap into the database.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Can you instead copy the HTML around the pop-up please? As much as you can, from page source.

Comment: @Alichino this is the source code from the pop-up. Not sure if I am doing this right, but here you go: https://pastebin.com/Wv5sE0q2

Comment: Adarsh below could be right. The whole page is inside an iframe. Try driver.switch_to.frame("mwmFrame") before you interact with the pop-up.

Comment: @Alichino is mwmFrame a placeholder name here? because Python is telling me said frame does not exist.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML here in your question but NOT the entire HTML. I looked at the link and I can't read Italian and I can't find the close button/element you are trying to locate and click.

Comment: @JeffC sorry for the late, should be ok now.

Comment: The relevant HTML needs to be edited into this question. The pastebin link at some point will go away leaving this question with no context. External links for *additional* information are fine but all the relevant bits needed to answer this question MUST be in the question itself.

Comment: @JeffC sorry for the delay, here you go.

Answer (score -1):

Chances are there that the pop up is in iframe.
So you need to switch to the frame before closing the pop up.

```
Driver.SwitchTo().frame("frame xpath");

Driver.findElement("enter your xpath to close popup").click();

Driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but you probably missed two points:
1) I am using python
2) the xpath to close the pop-up is dynamic, meaning that it will change upon refresh.